# Hieararchical data in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In webforms I used a repeater inside a repeater(Hieararchical model). How can I achieve the same in MVC?

Example:

```
Data1           Data2
 subdata1        subddata3
 subdata2        subdata4

Data3            data4
 subdata5         subdata7
 subdata6         subdata8
```

I also require a two column layout as shown above. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember where I read this, but it applies to you:

> -- But won't we nead at least a repeater control in MVC?
>   -- We have a repeater control. It's called a for each loop

Let's say your view model has a property called `Data` of type `IEnumerable<SuperDuper>`. To iterate over it, you'd just do

```
<% foreach (var sd in Model.Data) { %>
<!-- write out fancy stuff -->
<% } <%>
```

To iterate over subdata, let's say that `SuperDuper` has a property named `SubData` that's also an `IEnumerable<Something>`. Nothing stops you from doing

```
<% foreach (var sd in Model.Data) { %>
<!-- write out some fancy stuff -->
    <% foreach (var sub in sd.SubData) { %>
    <!-- write out some more fancy stuff -->
    <% } 
 } %>
```

For the two-column layout, resort to CSS.

---

And since Razor is on it's way, I can't resist to show you what those examples would look like with the new engine:

```
@foreach (var sd in Model.Data) {
<!-- write out fancy stuff -->
}


@foreach (var sd in Model.Data) {
<!-- write out some fancy stuff -->
    @foreach (var sub in sd.SubData) {
    <!-- write out some more fancy stuff -->
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And with [spark view engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/) you do this:

```
<div each="var item in Model.Data">
   ${item.Title}
   <div each="var subItem in item.SubData" style="padding-left: 20px">
       ${subItem.Title}
       <!-- Do some fancy stuff -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Razor? Yuck! ;)